# using clipboard to check when macro is finished

Tags: excel, vba, autohotkey

I'm starting an Excel macro from an AutoHotKey script and then waits for it to finish with the use of the clipboard. The Excel macro ends with a line that puts k into the clipboard:

```
With New MSForms.DataObject
    .SetText k
    .PutInClipboard
End With
```

The autohotkey script then has the line:

```
Loop {
} Until clipboard = "k"
```

That runs while the macro is running.
When the excel macro is finished it puts k into the clipboard and autohotkey detects that and proceeds with the script. The thing is though that it's not working. I get an error that Excel can't use the clipboard. It's used by another application, which I guess is autohotkey.

Is there a way to solve this? Or is there another way to let the script and the macro speak with each other? I want to start the macro from an autohotkey script and then wait for the macro to finish before resuming the script. This is the autohotkey script:

```
^!a::

OrdersLeftToPick:
click 400, 460
clipwait, 70
sleep, 1000

click 8, 2400
sleep, 100

send ^k   ;Ctrl + K, starts the macro

loop {
} until clipboard = "k" ;wait until "k" is in the clipboard then resume the script

sleep, 1000

goto OrdersLeftToPick
```

Comment: Why not just call the macro directly, instead of using hotkeys?

Comment: The script does alot of things, one of them is starting the macro. It clicks on different parts of the screen, performing different tasks. It then repeats and runs over and over. Check the goto line at the end of the script. It's an automatic thing. So it should start the macro, want for it to finish and then resume the script!

Comment: The implementation here is indeed questionable, but to not get too much into that, maybe just try putting like a `Sleep, 500` or whatever inside your Loop instead of leaving it empty. Might just do the trick.

Comment: Maybe try using `ClipWait` as per the help, "It's better to use this command than a loop of your own that checks to see if this clipboard is blank. This is because the clipboard is never opened by this command, and thus it performs better and avoids any chance of interfering with another application that may be using the clipboard."

Comment: https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/112033-trying-to-run-an-excel-macro-from-ahk/

Comment: Clipwait worked but not as I wanted. In the macro data is copied between sheets and that triggers clipwait. I want to trigger it in the end of the macro. Anyone has a better idea? I want AHK to start the macro and then wait for Excel to send some kind of signal that the macro is finished and then resume the script.

Comment: @Jens you could count how many times clipwait is triggered, or see my answer using StdOut . . .  Worst case scenario, have your excel macro write to a file at the end and have your ahk loop check to see if that file exists . . .

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the the penultimate example on the AHK Help "Run" page which explains how to use WScript.Shell.Exec to do something that may help (return stdout with a result, such as "Done" to your ahk script).
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm#StdOut

Here is an implementation:

```
;// The following runs a command (add.vbs but could be an excel macro, too) 
;// and retrieves its output (could be a message, e.g., "Done", too) via StdOut:

InputBox, x,,Enter two integer numbers  ;// two numbers to add
MsgBox % """" RunWaitOne("add.vbs " x) """" ;// returns, via stdout, the result in quotes
ExitApp

RunWaitOne(command)
{
    shell := ComObjCreate("WScript.Shell")
    exec := shell.Exec(ComSpec " /C cscript " command)
    return Substr(exec.StdOut.ReadAll(), 109) ;// remove 109 characters in WScript header
}

/* "add.vbs"  This is the external command:
a=33 ' some defauls
b=4
if WScript.Arguments.Count > 0 Then
    a=cint(WScript.Arguments.Item(0))
    b=cint(WScript.Arguments.Item(1))
End If

x=a+b  ' result (or, x="Done")

' This is how to get the result back:
Dim StdOut : Set StdOut = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetStandardStream(1)
StdOut.Write x
*/
```

Hth,